# How to move an object in random manner or change direction randomly

Tags: python, animation, blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to move an object in 3d environment using blender python script similar to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bEo8YRHysp8. I tried with the following code but ended up in jerks in movement and also the movement was not clear. Please help me thanks in advance.

```
import bpy
import math
import mathutils
import random

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.clear()
ob = bpy.data.objects.get("Cube")
ob.location = mathutils.Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

# every frame change, this function is called.
def my_handler(scene):
if random.randint(1, 10) > 9:
    x = random.uniform(-0.7, 0.7)
    #print (x)
    vec = mathutils.Vector((0.0, x, 0.0))
    ob.location = ob.location + vec
else:
    vec = mathutils.Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
    ob.location = ob.location + vec


bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```